# Rasterising shared shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I am trying to rasterise [this shapefile](http://dropcanvas.com/63yst) of ancient woodland across England. When I do it I just get a black Tif with out any positive values (just 0 for min and 0 for max). If I change the styling to singleband pseudcolour and manually input a max value of 1, QGIS (2.18.11) crashes.

I've done this in the past for viewsheds which had an integer field called DN and values of 1 which represented land with views to my observation point. I added an integer field in the ancient woodland table, giving each feature a value of 1 but the DN field does not appear in the drop down menu within the rasterisation window.

I need to do this for another 20 shapefiles so can anyone suggest a fix or correction to my method?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the GRASS tool **v.to.rast.value** which (when using the default options) should create an output with values from `nan` to `1`:

[image: Raster output]